# How to navigate back a StackNavigator when Tabs clicked twice?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a TabNavigator with three tabs. In each of these three tabs are StackNavigators.

How can I navigate the StackNavigator back if the user clicks the same tab-button twice?

[image]

My current approach is just doing.... nothing..

```
tabBarComponent: ({jumpToIndex, ...props, navigation}) => (
    <TabBarBottom {...props} jumpToIndex={index => {
      const { state } = navigation,
            { routes } = state;

      console.log(routes);

      if (state.index === index) {
        console.log(index);

        const resetTabAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: 'Dishes',
          action: NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Dishes' })],
          })
        });
        // props.navigation.dispatch(resetTabAction);
        navigation.dispatch(resetTabAction);

      } else {
        jumpToIndex(index);
      }
    }}/>
  ),
```

**Edit:**
I now added `DishesScreen.router = DishesStack.router;` to the component which is wrapping the inner StackNavigator. Now I can see the sub navigator in the routes and states. But Screen1 (Dish) is missing. There is just one route: DishList...

Maybe for a better understanding my components:

**App** Component render() -> **AppNavigator** *(TabNavigator - Deals, Dishes, Favorites)*

**Dishes** Component render() -> **DishesStack** *(StackNavigator - DishList, Dish)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: does jumpToIndex fire on second press?

Comment: Yes, and I see the index in the console on the second press correctly but the NavigationActions doesn't have any effect.. Dishes is just the name of the Tab.. Where do I need to "communicate" or "delegate" to the StackNavigator? There is no reference or anything else to it...

Comment: Dishes is the Tab1 or Screen1 of StackNavigator?

Comment: Dishes is the Tab..

Comment: How do you add the StackNavigator? render inside the Tab1 component?

Comment: In the App.js I am rendering the TabNavigator. For each Tab I have a TabXYScreen.js. In the render() of this components I render the StackNavigator. I render the StackNavigator with mode 'modal'.

Comment: Ok so you need to navigate to Screen1 of StackNavigator because you are already on Dishes (Tab1) component.

Comment: How can I tell the StackNavigator to navigate to XY from the TabComponent of the TabNavigator? Are the routeNames in my code wrong? Unfortunately I didn't understand the routeNames and the index of the NavigationActions correctly...

Comment: How do you tell StackNavigator to go Screen1 to Screen2? When you press second time on the tab you are already on 'Dishes' screen, your first action is to navigate to Dishes so I think navigator is not doing anything. What you need to do I believe when index the same as state.index you should check the current route and if its Screen2 of StackNavigator you should do navigation.goBack()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed to pass the navigation prop all down the components..

```
<AppNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} ..... />

<DishesStack navigation={this.props.navigation} .... />
```

and it's also neccessary to pass the router if the navigator is wrapped by a component:

```
DishesScreen.router = DishesStack.router;
```

See this section: [Nesting Navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting#Nesting-a-Navigator-in-a-Component)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
if (state.index === index) {
    dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Dishes })],
    }));
}else{
    jumpToIndex(index);
}
```